# Select old kernel of vserver without console access

Tags: boot, server, grub2, 20.04, kernel

I installed a new kernel on my vserver via SSH. After rebooting it doesn't start anymore.

I'm able to access to a "rescue-mode" where I can connect via SSH and access the vserver via a mount entry `/rescue`. This basically allows me to read/write files of the vserver.

**How can I change back to the previously used kernel?**

All solutions I found require a startable system (e.g. `update-grub`) or access to the console during startup (like press `SHIFT` during startup). It feels like a simple question where I should have found an existing question/answer - just I didn't :(

**Edit:**
The installation was done during a routine update task that I do. I start `aptitude` press `u` (update) press `U` (update package list) press twice `g` (mark upgradable/install).

**More background info**: my vserver provider says that their system does not support compressed kernels and that extracting the kernel would be the solution. They suggest using [this  script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/scripts/extract-vmlinux) + `update-grub`, this is why some kernels are named like `vmlinuz-5.x.0-xx-generic.d`. These are the two extracted kernels of the first installation (by the provider). Without knowing all of this, I run the previously described update and restarted. Now it is too late to follow the providers instruction and my plan is to activate one of the extracted kernels. BTW - I wonder why my provider cannot just run ubuntu kernels as they are installed by ubuntu, but that is another story.

**List of existing files.** However, I've already changed the symbolic links initrd.img and vmlinuz to the desired version. Before that it was 5.4.0-66.

```
root@RESCUESYSTEM:/rescue/boot# ls -lah
total 394M
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Mar 15 21:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 36 root root 4.0K Mar  3 19:34 ..
-rw-------  1 root root 3.9M May 11  2020 System.map-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 4.5M May 21  2020 System.map-5.3.0-55-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 4.6M May 21  2020 System.map-5.4.0-33-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 4.6M Sep 10  2020 System.map-5.4.0-48-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 4.6M Jan 18 16:31 System.map-5.4.0-65-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 4.6M Jan 27 21:44 System.map-5.4.0-66-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 213K May 11  2020 config-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 231K May 21  2020 config-5.3.0-55-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 233K May 21  2020 config-5.4.0-33-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 233K Sep 10  2020 config-5.4.0-48-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 233K Jan 18 16:31 config-5.4.0-65-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 233K Jan 27 21:44 config-5.4.0-66-generic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 15 22:26 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 Mar 15 21:54 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.4.0-33-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  24M Mar 12 20:33 initrd.img-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  25M Mar 12 20:33 initrd.img-5.3.0-55-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  48M Mar 12 20:33 initrd.img-5.4.0-33-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  26M Mar 12 20:32 initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  48M Mar 12 20:31 initrd.img-5.4.0-65-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  48M Mar 12 20:30 initrd.img-5.4.0-66-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 Feb 23 20:02 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-65-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Mar 15 21:54 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 8.0M May 11  2020 vmlinuz-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  11M May 21  2020 vmlinuz-5.3.0-55-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  43M May 27  2020 vmlinuz-5.3.0-55-generic.d
-rw-------  1 root root  12M May 21  2020 vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  43M Jun  4  2020 vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic.d
-rw-------  1 root root  12M Sep 10  2020 vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  12M Jan 18 16:45 vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  12M Jan 27 22:14 vmlinuz-5.4.0-66-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Feb 23 20:02 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic
```

Comment: You installed a new kernel? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1323941/edit) to clearly explain how and why you did that. If you followed online instructions, a link would be helpful. Also add the complete output of `ls -lah /boot`.

Comment: Do you own the virtual server? Cuz on a virtual server I would assume you can not upgrade a kernel. You create a new virtual server with the new kernel and ditch the old one.

Comment: @Rinzwind it is a virtual server hosted by a provider where I have root access via SSH. AFAIK I could do anything with it - except any interaction while OpenSSH isn't started yet (e.G. GRUB).

Comment: That would mean you should not touch kernels.  With google cloud for instance a new Ubuntu (ie. a new kernel) release means to set up a new virtual server and connect your personal disks to it.